# How to get minimum date by each records from multiple records

Tags: vb.net, greatest-n-per-group, sql

I would like to get the minimum date of each record in my table having multiple entry of date with one primary key. Take a look at my table:

```
   CaseNo     Entry_date   
   ABC-001     2/12/13
   ABC-002     2/09/13
   ABC-001     1/01/13
   ABC-001     1/31/13
   ABC-002     1/01/13
   ABC-003     2/01/12
   ABC-003     2/18/13
```

I want to have this result:

```
       CaseNo     Entry_date    Min_date
       ABC-001     2/12/13      1/01/13
       ABC-002     2/09/13      1/09/13
       ABC-001     1/01/13      1/01/13
       ABC-001     1/31/13      1/01/13
       ABC-002     1/09/13      1/09/13 
       ABC-003     2/01/12      2/01/13
       ABC-003     2/18/13      2/01/13
```

I want to get the minimum date of each CaseNo recorded on my table.

I tried this code:

```
Select CaseNo,Entry_date, Min(Entry_date) as Min_date
from mytable group by CaseNo
```

Result is this:

```
   CaseNo     Entry_date    Min_date
   ABC-001     1/01/13      1/01/13
   ABC-002     1/09/13      1/09/13 
   ABC-003     2/01/12      2/01/13
```

The code remove the row not having the minimum date. I want to display all records with their minimum date as Min_date.

Comment: Also, when asking sql questions, it helps to provide code to generate your example, ie: a CREATE TABLE and an INSERT statement.  That way answerers have a table to test their answers on without having to manually copy your example.  This was a fairly straightforward one so not really necessary, but good to keep in mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get the minimum date of each Record (Repost)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208159/how-to-get-the-minimum-date-of-each-record-repost)

Comment: @Jakob: doesn't it make more sense to close the second duplicate, rather than the first one?

Comment: @halfer: Yes, but it seems that the OP is only active on the newer post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
  CaseNo,
  Entry_date,
  (SELECT MIN(Entry_date) FROM Cases subc WHERE subc.CaseNo=c.CaseNo GROUP BY CaseNo) AS MinEntryDate
FROM Cases c
```

Answer (score 9):

Unsure what RDBMS you're using, but two approaches come to mind.

### JOIN against derived table

Create a derived table of (`CaseNo`, `MIN(Entry_date)`) rows, and join that against your primary table:

```sql
    SELECT CaseNo, Entry_date, d.Min_date AS "Min_date"
      FROM tbl
INNER JOIN (  SELECT CaseNo, MIN(Entry_date) AS "Min_date"
                FROM tbl
            GROUP BY 1) d
        ON tbl.CaseNo = d.CaseNo;
```

### Use analytic (window) functions

If your RDBMS supports it, you can skip the derived table and ask for your records with the minimum `Entry_date` by `CaseNo` provided by the system:

```sql
SELECT CaseNo, Entry_date, MIN(Entry_date) OVER (PARTITION BY CaseNo) AS "Min_date"
  FROM tbl;
```

Comment: @Neolisk, indeed!  I wish support for (and knowledge of) window/analytic functions was more widespread.

Comment: @Juan: I recommend avoiding the phrase "It doesn't work" - for some reason it seems to discourage the writer from saying what is actually happening (and I often downvote for lack of effort). What is pilcrow here meant to say to you if you don't explain? Do you get an error? Do you get results? What results do you get? Have you tried modifying it for your particular use-case?