# Query to get the minimum date of each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I would like to get the minimum date of each record in my table having multiple entry of date with one primary key. Take a look at my table:

```
   CaseNo     Entry_date   
   ABC-001     2/12/13
   ABC-002     2/09/13
   ABC-001     1/01/13
   ABC-001     1/31/13
   ABC-002     1/01/13
   ABC-003     2/01/12
   ABC-003     2/18/13
```

I want to have this result:

```
       CaseNo     Entry_date    Min_date
       ABC-001     2/12/13      1/01/13
       ABC-002     2/09/13      1/09/13
       ABC-001     1/01/13      1/01/13
       ABC-001     1/31/13      1/01/13
       ABC-002     1/09/13      1/09/13 
       ABC-003     2/01/12      2/01/13
       ABC-003     2/18/13      2/01/13
```

I want to get the minimum date of each CaseNo recorded on my table. I tried this code:

```
Select
    CaseNo,Entry_date, Min(Entry_date) as Min_date
from mytable group by CaseNo
```

Result is this:

```
   CaseNo     Entry_date    Min_date
   ABC-001     1/01/13      1/01/13
   ABC-002     1/09/13      1/09/13 
   ABC-003     2/01/12      2/01/13
```

The code remove the row not having the minimum date. I want to display all records with their minimum date as `Min_date`.

Comment: Is this SQLServer? Shouldn't the smallest value for ABC-002 be 1/01/13? Also, why have you included "(repost)" in the title of this question?

Comment: yes I tried to used the over (partition by CaseNo) but there's a error incorrect syntax near to the keyword 'over'

Comment: Juan Filipe: You haven't answered any of my questions (although Vinayak did answer one of them). I'll repeat the most important one: **Is this SQLServer**, and if not, which RDBMS is it? The answer **will** affect how this question can be resolved.

Comment: @Vinayak: Thanks, I didn't notice the older question previously.

Comment: YES it is a SQLSERVER...

Comment: Which version of SQLServer? The `over` syntax in all of the supplied answers should work in all versions of SQLServer from SQLServer 2005 onwards.

Comment: Voting to close as dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971794/how-to-get-minimum-date-by-each-records-from-multiple-records. Please don't ask questions more than once, as it risks causing duplicate effort.

Comment: The answer was already provided for you on your other post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14972988/64161.  I will delete my answer here and vote to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it either with CTE or subquery. CTE has better performance.

Subquery version

```
SELECT
  CaseNo,
  Entry_date,
  (SELECT MIN(Entry_date) FROM Cases subc WHERE subc.CaseNo=c.CaseNo GROUP BY CaseNo) AS MinEntryDate
FROM Cases c;
```

CTE version

```
WITH CasesMinEntryDate(CaseNo, MinEntryDate) AS 
(
  SELECT CaseNo, MIN(Entry_date) FROM Cases GROUP BY CaseNo
)
SELECT
  c.CaseNo,
  Entry_date,
  MinEntryDate
FROM Cases c
INNER JOIN CasesMinEntryDate cmed ON c.CaseNo=cmed.CaseNo;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0feee/8

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.Case_No,
       a.Entry_date, 
       Min(b.Entry_date) as Min_date 
from   mytable a, 
       mytable b
where  a.case_no = b.case_no
group by a.Case_No, a.entry_date
order by a.entry_date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe6bd/2